# WPF displaying differently on different computers

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-xp

I am running Windows XP on my computer, and another computer also is running Windows XP.

In my WPF application, I've changed the styles of my buttons to appear as if they are not highlighting when rolled over, clicked, etc.

On my computer, this is the behavior that is occurring.  On the other Windows XP system, I am seeing some outlining of the buttons with I roll over them or click.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

**EDIT**

Here is the Button itself

```
        <Button Click="Next_Click" Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Black" Background="Black" IsTabStop="False" DockPanel.Dock="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="154" Name="NextOffers">
            <Image Source="Images/offer_right_arrow.jpg" Width="100" Height="154" MaxWidth="100" MaxHeight="154" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" MinWidth="100" MinHeight="154" ></Image>
        </Button>
```

Also this Style, too.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle">
    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="ListBox_MouseLeftButtonDown"></EventSetter>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Border Name="Border" Padding="0,0,2,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Black"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I don't have a template made for this button, obviously.

I am loading my ResourceDictionaries dynamically in the code behind.

Comment: Do both computers have the same Windows theme applied?

Comment: No, they don't.  My work computer's theme is controlled by AD's group policy (boo) and the other computer is controlled by the group policy of another company office.

Comment: you better apply custom styles for elements.. seems like your controls are getting styles from system's default, that is why it looks different in other themes.

Comment: I am applying custom styles to the elements!  That is why I am confused.

Comment: Can you post your styles and how you are applying them etc.

Comment: @TheGeek: Custom styles can inherit from the system defaults if you aren't explicitly creating new templates for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need a custom control template for your buttons.  The default control template for most WPF controls is dependent upon the Windows theme that is selected, so that a button follows the theme whether you're on the Windows Classic theme, Aero, Royale, or whatever.  If you want it to look **exactly the same** no matter what OS or theme the user has chosen, you'll save yourself a lot of headache using a custom control template.

Google "Show me the template" for an app that will give you the control template source (XAML) for each theme.  This is a good starting point for creating custom templates.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're seeing is most likely due to the default `Button` `Chrome`. You can apply all sorts of styling, but if you leave that `Chrome` intact, the Windows theme is going to rear its ugly head.

You'll need to recreate the `ControlTemplate` itself.

Comment: If I use a control template, do I have to explicitly define the click event in the template?

Comment: No; I've restyled buttons so they don't show OS/theme-specific styles, and I've never had to set up click events. WPF controls are "lookless," but we have the set of controls we do because each has different *behaviour.*  So, you might restyle a button to, say, show a video, not because you wanted to show the video but because you wanted the behaviour of a button.